# Mongo aggregate and count over n fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Im having trouble understanding MongoDB's Aggregation framework. Basically my JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "param1": true,
    "param2": false,
    "param3": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "param1": true,
    "param2": false,
    "param3": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "param1": false,
    "param2": true,
    "param3": false
  }
]
```

I want to count how many documents have, for example, param1 == true, param2 == true and so on.
In this case the expected result should be:

```
count_param1: 2
count_param2: 1
count_param3: 1
```

The trick here is that param can be param1 .. paramN, so basically I either need to do a distinct and specify exactly which fields im interested in or can I "group on" all fields starting with "param".

What is the recommended approach?

---

Further explanation:

The SQL equivalent would be to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(param1) AS param1
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY param1
```

For each column (but in one query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. 
Check out my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056011/grouping-over-multiple-fields-in-mongodb) and chridam's excellent answer.

A perfect solution for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use aggregation, as there is a built-in helper [count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) for this:

```
> db.collection.count({ "param1" : true })
```

You can create a simple function that takes the parameter name as argument and gives back the count:

```
> param_count = function(param_name) {
    count_obj = {}
    count_obj[param_name] = true
    return db.collection.count(count_obj)
}
```

While it is technically possible to get the counts for all the params in one aggregation pipeline, it's infeasible for 1 million+ rows and it will be better to do one aggregation pipeline per param name. I'm not well-versed in SQL, but I am guessing when you give the SQL equivalent and say you'd do them all in "one query" you mean you'd send one batch of SQL but it would essentially be a concatenation of different queries to group and count, so it's not much different from the solution I have given.

The count can use an index on `paramN` if one exists.

Comment: Tried it. One param_count without index on a db with 300 000 documents took 0.2 s. Too slow.